# How to convert integer regex captures to array of integers in Julia 0.4?

Tags: regex, julia

I'm unable to convert integer regular expression captures values to an array of integers in Julia 0.4.

In Julia 0.3 I could do this with int(), basically like:

```
c = ["1", "2"] ;
int(c)
```

But in Julia 0.4, this works for regular strings:

```
julia> c = ["1", "2"] ;

julia> int(c)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
```

but doesn't work with substrings (i.e. regex captures):

```
re_dcIV = r"^
([IV])(\S+)\s+
(\d+)\s+
(\d+)\s+
DC\s+
(\S+)\s*$"x ;

line = "V1 1 2 DC 1" ;

m = match( re_dcIV, line ) ;

c = m.captures ;
println( "$c\n" ) ;

nodes = int(c[3:4]) ;
```

which produces:

```
julia> nodes = int(c[3:4]) ;
WARNING: int(x::AbstractArray) is deprecated, use round(Int64,x) instead.
 in depwarn at deprecated.jl:63
 in int at deprecated.jl:49
while loading no file, in expression starting on line 0
ERROR: MethodError: `round` has no method matching round(::Type{Int64}, ::SubString{UTF8String})
Closest candidates are:
  round{T<:Integer}(::Type{T<:Integer}, ::Integer)
  round{T<:Integer}(::Type{T<:Integer}, ::Float16)
  round{T<:Union{Signed,Unsigned}}(::Type{T<:Union{Signed,Unsigned}}, ::Base.MPFR.BigFloat)
  ...
 in round at floatfuncs.jl:72
 in int at deprecated.jl:51
```

The type of the capture array is:

```
Union{SubString{UTF8String},Void}["V","1","1","2","1"]
```

and I'm not able to execute int(c[3:4]) on a subset of this Union beastie.  Is there a way to convert this substring array to a string array so that I can run int()?  What's the best way to convert this splice to an array of integers?

Comment: The deprecated method should work and the warning message should print a valid suggestion.  Please report this issue to https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/new.

Comment: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/12847

Answer (score 3):

The most straight forward way seems to be using a `map` with `parse`:

```
julia> map(x -> parse(Int, x), c[3:4])
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
```